# Grid columns without float

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to place seven columns of the same size in one row:

```
.seven-cols .col-hard-1 {
  width: 14.28%;
  *width: 14.28%;
  float: left;
}
```

However, `float:left` screws up the all the next blocks on the page. Is there a way to make this grid without using `float`?

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRjGBQ)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex;` on the container and `flex-grow: 1;` and `flex-basis: 0;` on the items to make them all take up the same amount of available space.

```css
.seven-cols {
  display: flex;
}
.seven-cols .col-hard-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="seven-cols">
  <div class="col-hard-1">
    one
  </div>

  <div class="col-hard-1">
    two
  </div>

  <div class="col-hard-1">
    three
  </div>

  <div class="col-hard-1">
    four
  </div>

  <div class="col-hard-1">
    five
  </div>
  <div class="col-hard-1">
    six
  </div>
  <div class="col-hard-1">
    seven
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a great solution. I totally forgot about flex. Thanks!